fill gaps in outer join in redshift
I have a table that contains products and sales data. Unfortunately, not every month a given product was sold, and I would like unsold products in a given month to also be shown. In Oracle, the query is built this way: https://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/270646.htm.
I would like to do it similarly in Redshift, but I can't use the partitioning described here. Can I easily replace it somehow?
data sample:
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT to_date('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2023-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2023-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2023-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d FROM dual
)
, product_sales as(
    --Yanuary
    SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 3 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 8 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 9 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    
    UNION ALL
    
    --February
    SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 5 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 2 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 1 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    
    UNION ALL
    
    --March
--  SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 5 AS sale_amount FROM dual
--  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 7 AS sale_amount FROM dual
--  UNION ALL
--  SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 1 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    
    UNION ALL
    
    --April
    SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 1 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 2 AS sale_amount FROM dual
--  UNION ALL
--  SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 1 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    
    UNION ALL
    
    --May
    SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 6 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 4 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 2 AS sale_amount FROM dual
)


SELECT ps.prod_id, ps.prod_name, nvl(ps.sale_amount, 0) AS sale_amount, da.d AS sale_date
FROM product_sales ps
PARTITION BY(ps.prod_id, ps.prod_name)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dates da ON ps.sale_date = da.d
ORDER BY da.d, ps.prod_id


See example
select p.prod_id,p.prod_name,dates.d, coalesce(month_sale_amount,0) month_sale_amount
from dates
left join (select distinct prod_id,prod_name from product_sales) p on 1=1
left join(
  select prod_id,date_trunc('month',sale_date) sale_date
    ,sum(sale_amount) as month_sale_amount
  from product_sales
  group by prod_id,date_trunc('month',sale_date)
) total_sales on sale_date=dates.d and total_sales.prod_id=p.prod_id
order by dates.d,p.prod_id




prod_id
prod_name
d
month_sale_amount




1
test1
2023-01-01
3


2
test2
2023-01-01
8


3
test3
2023-01-01
9


1
test1
2023-02-01
5


2
test2
2023-02-01
2


3
test3
2023-02-01
1


1
test1
2023-03-01
0


2
test2
2023-03-01
7


3
test3
2023-03-01
0


1
test1
2023-04-01
1


2
test2
2023-04-01
2


3
test3
2023-04-01
0


1
test1
2023-05-01
6


2
test2
2023-05-01
4


3
test3
2023-05-01
2



fiddle

Why LEFT JOIN ... ON 1=1 rather than CROSS JOIN ...?

You were nearly there:
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT to_date('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2023-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2023-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2023-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS d 
)
, product_sales as(
    --Yanuary
    SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 3 AS sale_amount 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 8 AS sale_amount 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 9 AS sale_amount 
    
    UNION ALL
    
    --February
    SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 5 AS sale_amount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 2 AS sale_amount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 1 AS sale_amount
    
    UNION ALL
    
    --March
--  SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 5 AS sale_amount FROM dual
--  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 7 AS sale_amount 
--  UNION ALL
--  SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 1 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    
    UNION ALL
    
    --April
    SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 1 AS sale_amount 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 2 AS sale_amount 
--  UNION ALL
--  SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 1 AS sale_amount FROM dual
    
    UNION ALL
    
    --May
    SELECT 1 AS prod_id, 'test1' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 6 AS sale_amount 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS prod_id, 'test2' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 4 AS sale_amount 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS prod_id, 'test3' AS prod_name, to_date('2023-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS sale_date, 2 AS sale_amount 
)
, spooge as (
SELECT prod_id, prod_name, coalesce(ps.sale_amount, 0) AS sale_amount, sale_date
FROM product_sales ps
UNION ALL
  select prod_id, prod_name, sale_amount, sale_date 
  from (select prod_id, prod_name, 0 as sale_amount, da.d as sale_date
        from product_sales          
        cross JOIN dates da 
        group by 1, 2, 3, 4
       ) xd    
)
select prod_id, prod_name, sum(sale_amount) as sale_amount, sale_date
from spooge
group by 1, 2, 4
ORDER BY  prod_id, sale_date


One of the options is to generate rows for all products and months...
Select      g.prod_id, g.prod_name, SUM(Coalesce(s.sale_amount, 0)) as sale_amount, g.sale_month 
From       ( Select     To_Char(dts.d, 'YYYY-MM') as sale_month, s.prod_id, s.prod_name 
             From       dates dts
             Cross Join ( Select Distinct prod_id, prod_name From product_sales ) s
           ) g
Left Join   product_sales s ON(To_Char(s.sale_date, 'YYYY-MM') = g.sale_month And s.prod_id = g.prod_id)
Group By    g.prod_id, g.prod_name, sale_month
Order By    sale_month, g.prod_id

R e s u l t  :



prod_id
prod_name
sale_amount
sale_month




1
test1
3
2023-01


2
test2
8
2023-01


3
test3
9
2023-01


1
test1
5
2023-02


2
test2
2
2023-02


3
test3
1
2023-02


1
test1
0
2023-03


2
test2
7
2023-03


3
test3
0
2023-03


1
test1
1
2023-04


2
test2
2
2023-04


3
test3
0
2023-04


1
test1
6
2023-05


2
test2
4
2023-05


3
test3
2
2023-05



fiddle

No need to make the cross product a sub-query?
